# Display QML structure without having to declare its Window in QML file

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, qml, pyside

After creating widgets using QML and linking them to a model in Python, I want to display them in a window to see the results and test it. I do this by wrapping the QML with a `Window` type, like below:

```
Window { 
    visible: true
    
    # "Relevant" QML in here

}
```

My issue here is that when I import this QML file as a structure in another QML file, it is displayed as a separate window (because it still has the `Window { ... }` wrapping its code). I then need to navigate to the first QML file and manually delete the `Window` line, which is tiresome and error-prone.

Is there a way to switch from "View this QML structure as an independent widget in its own window", to "view this QML structure a a sub-widget in another window", without having to edit the QML directly?

As an example, consider this QML view and Python model:

`MyView.qml`

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window { visible: true  # this is the line I'd like to remove ...

ColumnLayout {
   CheckBox {
        id: checkbox
        checked: model.active
        onClicked: model.active = checkbox.checked
        text: model.name
   }
   SpinBox {
        id: spinbox
        from: -10
        value: model.value
        editable: true
        enabled: checkbox.checked
        onValueChanged: model.value = value
    }
    Button {
        text: 'Print Value'
        onClicked: model.print()
    }
}

}  # ... and the enclosing curly brace here, too
```

`MyModel.py`

```
from __future__ import annotations

import sys

from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc, QtGui as qtg, QtQml as qtqml


class MyModel(qtc.QObject):
    nameChanged = qtc.Signal(str)
    valueChanged = qtc.Signal(int)
    activeStateChanged = qtc.Signal(bool)

    def __init__(
            self,
            name: str = 'My Model',
            value: int = 5,
            active: bool = False,
            parent: qtc.QObject = None
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self._name = name
        self._value = value
        self._active = active

    # The methods below show the model in action
    # but aren't crucial for the question itself

    def as_dict(self) -> dict[str, int | None]:
        """
        Returns the model's name and value as a dictionary 
        (value is None if the Model is not active).
        """
        return {self._name: self._value if self._active else None}

    @qtc.Slot()
    def print(self) -> None:
        """Print the current Model's name and value."""
        print(self.as_dict())

    @qtc.Property(str, notify=nameChanged)
    def name(self) -> float:
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(
            self,
            new_name: float,
    ) -> None:
        if new_name != self._name:
            self._name = new_name
            self.nameChanged.emit(new_name)

    @qtc.Property(int, notify=valueChanged)
    def value(self) -> int:
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(
            self,
            new_value: int,
    ) -> None:
        if new_value != self._value:
            self._value = new_value
            self.valueChanged.emit(new_value)

    @qtc.Property(bool, notify=activeStateChanged)
    def active(self) -> bool:
        return self._active

    @active.setter
    def active(
            self,
            new_active_state: bool,
    ) -> None:
        if new_active_state != self._active:
            self._active = new_active_state
            self.activeStateChanged.emit(new_active_state)


def mainloop() -> None:
    app = qtg.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    model = MyModel()

    engine = qtqml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("model", model)
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    engine.load('MyView.qml')

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainloop()
```

The code produces the window below, with the widgets and model working as expected:

[image]

But I would like to be able to obtain this same visualization without having to jump into the QML file and manually add the `Window { ... }` whenever I want to see the widget. Can I change anything in the `mainloop` function in order to indicate that I want to view the widget by itself?

Comment: Make the sub component into a sub-component.  Load it into a window as needed or use it directly without the `Window` wrapper if it needs to be embedded.

Comment: Thanks @RossRogers, I figured there must be a way to do just that (maybe directly in the Python code, when  instantiating the Application), but I'm not sure how. I appreciate if anyone can show me how to do it (or point me to an existing answer - I searched but couldn't find any).

Comment: Create a new file for the component.  QML Docs describe ["component files" here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#details)  Then you can reuse your component in multiple contexts.